# 3 Dimensional Data in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a data set in **`.csv`** files.

They are each two dimensional ( **multiple** columns and **multiple** rows ).

The third dimension being the depth of sixty or so files, labeled according to date.

I need to use these as one data set and don't know where to start.

Is there a tool set that handles this effectively?

I believe that my essential question is: **Is there a way to add the file name** of a .csv file **to the contents of the file and combine multiple .csv files together?**

Comment: can show us the data sample???

Comment: Probably you can just the filename as another column. But it is hard to say if we do not exactly know what you need.

Comment: Do you actually need to combine it in a file or just work with it as a 3 dimensional array in Python? The latter doesn't seem to be that hard to do. Im not sure if did understand your problem though. Some more info would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "file1.csv" contains

```
a,1
b,2
```

and "file2.csv" contains

```
aa,11
bb,22
```

you can put them together with something like

```
out = open("outfile.csv", "w")
for fname in ["file1.csv","file2.csv"]:
    with open(fname) as f:
        for line in f:
             out.write(line.rstrip() + ',' + fname + '\n')
out.close()
```

and get

```
a,1,file1.csv
b,2,file1.csv
aa,11,file2,csv
bb,22,file2.csv
```

You may also be interested in modules `os` (to remove the extension or a path before the name, for example) and maybe `fileinput` from the standard library.
Depending on the data it might also be better to construct a database (with `sqlite3`) instead.